# Azure Traffic Manger Priority Routing is not working

Tags: azure, routes, azure-traffic-manager

I created an Azure Traffic manager and routing with `Priority`.As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-routing-methods#a-name--priorityapriority-traffic-routing-method)

> The Traffic Manager profile contains a prioritized list of service
>   endpoints. By default, Traffic Manager sends all traffic to the
>   primary (highest-priority) endpoint. If the primary endpoint is not
>   available, Traffic Manager routes the traffic to the second endpoint.
>   If both the primary and secondary endpoints are not available, the
>   traffic goes to the third, and so on

**My Traffic Manager monitoring**

**Low Priority**

[image]

**High Priority**
[image]

I tried to increase the priority and decrease the priority but there is no change.

Still, you can see that traffic manager pointing towards the `teststatic` site alone

### Another question from the above doc

> If the primary endpoint is not available

Here what is mean by not available? As I'm using Azure Web Apps for my testing purpose, So I thought When **Stopping my webapp** could be **not available**. But I'm wrong, Even though I stop the web app, still, the traffic manager pointing the stopped web app. So I'm confused about what is mean by not available here?

Comment: What is your TTL set to on Traffic Manager? Remember that TM only responds to DNS queries so it may take some time until your system makes another DNS query.

Comment: @juunas TTL is 60 sec. Yes I'm trying with the TM DNS url in my browser,still not getting any change

Comment: You can also try running `nslookup yoursite.trafficmanager.net` in a command prompt (assuming you are on Windows) to see what TM answers.

Comment: @juunas I'm getting `DNS request timeout.timeout was 2 sec`

Comment: Did you replace "yoursite" with your DNS name? ;)

Comment: Yes I did. The full response is `DNS request timed out.timeout was 2 seconds.Server:  UnKnown Address:  192.168.1.1 Non-authoritative answer:Name:    waws-prod-ma1-003.cloudapp.net
Address:  52.172.54.225
Aliases:  xxx.trafficmanager.net
          xxxx.azurewebsites.net
          waws-prod-ma1-003.sip.azurewebsites.windows.net`

Comment: Hmm, you can try adding `/set timeout=10` to set the timeout higher (here 10 seconds). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/nslookup-set-timeout

Comment: The same issue,Also I noticed that `Ping xxx.trafficmanager.net` is also getting request timeout. But wierd is I can able to view my site in browser

Comment: Seems like a problem with your TM endpoint :/

Comment: I even tried with creating a new one which is having a single endpoint,now that endpoint is also not working. [Here](http://testdeevita.trafficmanager.net/) this is the my TM

Comment: I'm getting a DNS response on that. Could be something wrong with your DNS server?

Comment: Then it's ok but why the screen is showing like that . I expect to see my webapp. But it's not showing. Also the priority routing it's not working for me

Comment: Did you add the traffic manager host name to custom domains on the Web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your screenshots, the test endpoint monitor status is always a **Degraded** status. This indicated that the endpoint is not included in DNS reponses and does not receive traffic. So the Traffic Manager is still pointing towards the teststatic site alone. Traffic Manager considers an endpoint to be **ONLINE** only when the probe receives an HTTP 200 response back from the probe path If the monitoring protocol is HTTP or HTTPS. Any other non-200 response is a failure.

You need to [troubleshoot degraded state on Azure Traffic Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-troubleshooting-degraded) and see [Traffic Manager shows monitor status is degraded – Resolution](http://www.cloudmovement.co.uk/traffic-manager-shows-monitor-status-is-degraded-resolution/)

> what is mean by not available here?

The traffic manager chooses an endpoint based on the status of each endpoint (disabled endpoint are not returned), the current health of each endpoint and the chosen traffic-routing method. If the endpoint is not available, that is to say the endpoint is not included the DNS response or is an unhealthy endpoint. But an exception to this is if all endpoints are degraded, in which case all of them will be considered to be returned in the query response. You can get more details from [endpoint monitor status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-monitoring#endpoint-monitor-status).

> An endpoint is unhealthy when any of the following events occur: A
>   non-200 response is received (including a different 2xx code, or a
>   301/302 redirect); Request for client authentication; Timeout (the
>   timeout threshold is 10 seconds; Unable to connect.

Besides, Type `ipconfig /flushdns` to flush the DNS resolver cache when you [verity the Traffic Manager Settings.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-testing-settings)